# using pointers to set variables

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm working on a program that uses pointers to set the values of variables. For example, to set price to 19.95, I won't use the variable price, but the pointer variable *p_price.

The code below produces the following:

```
address of price=0x22fec8
contents of price=19.95
address of *p_price=0x22ffe0
contents of p_price=0x22ffe0
contents of *p_price=19.95
```

I'm trying to get the middle one to display the address of p_price, not *p_price. However, changing the code to display &p_price causes the program to crash without any indication of what's wrong.

Should the address of price be &*p_price

and the address of p_price be &price?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <random> // needed for Orwell devcpp

using namespace std;

int main(){
    float * p_price;
    *p_price=19.95;

    float price = *p_price; 

    cout <<"address of price="<<&price<<endl;
    cout <<"contents of price="<<price<<endl;
    cout <<"address of *p_price="<<&*p_price<<endl;
    cout <<"contents of p_price="<<p_price<<endl;
    cout <<"contents of *p_price="<<* p_price<<endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you assign a value to a pointer for which you didn't allocate memory. You are dereferencing `*p_price`, then assign `19.95` to it, but what address are you dereferencing? Because no memory was allocated for it, it points to some random location in memory, and this causes UB (undefined behaviour)

```
float * p_price; // no memory is allocated!!!!
// need to allocate memory for p_price, BEFORE dereferencing 
*p_price=19.95; // this is Undefined Behaviour
```

Comment: To keep the contents of p_price as the address, i should declare a new variable and set p_price equal to the address of that then?

Comment: Yes. A pointer only stores an adress, but as vsoftco said something needs to store the float number too...

Comment: yes, or do `float *p_price = new float;`, and now you have some reserved memory location to which `p_price` points. THEN, you can dereference it and safely put `19.95` into that memory slot.

Answer (score 1):

```
int main(){
     float * p_price;
    *p_price=19.95;
```

should be

```
int main(){
    float price;
     float * p_price = &price;
    *p_price=19.95;
```

a pointer has to point at something if you want to use it.

Answer (score 0):

In your code `p_price` is a pointer to `float`, but you dereference it before assigning it to point to a `float` instance. Try this instead:

```
int main(){
    float price;
    float * p_price = &price;
    *p_price=19.95;

    cout <<"address of price="<<&price<<endl;
    cout <<"contents of price="<<price<<endl;
    cout <<"address of p_price="<<&p_price<<endl;
    cout <<"contents of p_price="<<p_price<<endl;
    cout <<"contents of *p_price="<<*p_price<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, as I can see you are creating pointer to float, but this pointer is pointing to nothing.

```
int main() {
    //Bad code
    float* pointer;    //Okay, we have pointer, but assigned to nothing
    *pointer = 19.95f; //We are changing value of variable under pointer to 19.95...
                       //WAIT what? What variable!?
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //Good code
    float* pointer2 = new float(0f);
    //We are creating pointer and also variable with value of 0
    //Pointer is assigned to variable with value of 0, and that is good
    *pointer2 = 19.95f;
    //Now we are changing value of variable with 0 to 19.95, and that is okay.
    delete pointer2;
    //But in the end, we need to delete our allocated value, because we don't need this variable anymore, and also, read something about memory leek
    return 0;
}
```